# Automatic assignment of references to bibliography categories depending on origdate or date

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, chicago-style

I'm using `biblatex-chicago` with the `author-date` option. I love `biblatex` and `biblatex-chicago` and appreciate the work that has been put into it. I have a small question, however. I usually divide my bibliography into sections using

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{A}
```

in the preamble and then

```
\autocite{B}

\AddToCategory{A}{B}
```

following a citation of B.

Now I wonder, if it's possible to have a bibliography category:

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Before1900}
```

and have a reference be added automatically to the category `Before1900` if:

1. It has an origdate value and that value is lower than 1900;
2. It has no origdate value but the date value is lower than 1900.

I would be interested in such an option since it would enable me to automatically create a split bibliography according to the date a source was written/published.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`biblatex` allows us to filter the entries to be inserted in a bibliography.

First of all you have to define the conditions to be used using `\definebibcheck`

```
\defbibcheck{pre}{
  \iffieldint{origyear}
    {\ifnumless{\thefield{origyear}}{1900}
      {}
      {\skipentry}
    }
    {\iffieldint{year}
      {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{1900}
        {}
        {\skipentry}
      }
      {\skipentry}
    }
}

\defbibcheck{post}{
  \iffieldint{origyear}
    {\ifnumless{1899}{\thefield{origyear}}
      {}
      {\skipentry}
    }
    {\iffieldint{year}
      {\ifnumless{1899}{\thefield{year}}
        {}
        {\skipentry}
      }
      {
       \skipentry %comment out this line if unknown date check used as well.
      } 
    }
}
```

after that you can use the `check`s in a `\printbibliography` command

```
\printbibliography[check=pre,title={Before 1900}]

\printbibliography[chek=post,title={Post 1900}]
```

*EDIT*

To create a third class of entries, those with unclear dating, the check could be as follows:

```
\defbibcheck{dateunknown}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{year}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{origyear}}
  }
    {}
    {\skipentry}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. Is there a way that I can make a third bibliography where works would appear that LACK both an `origdate` and a `date` field? (For works that are of unclear dating.)

Comment: I get an error message when I try to use the third check. I've tried to play around with it but I'm too inept at code to make it work. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Mårten Indeed there were a few typos and mistakes. They should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! Now the undated references appear in a separate bibliography, but they still also appear in the check=post category. Do you know how to prevent them from being listed there as well?

Comment: @Mårten it was a catch all condition in post. See the updated post

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I guess it should read        \skipentry %comment out this line if unknown date check IS NOT used.