# Filtering biblatex entries based on timespan

Tags: biblatex

I have seen the answer to [biblatex filter on arbitrary field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333682/biblatex-filter-on-arbitrary-field).

But, how can I filter biblatex entries based on a time span, for instance to select papers published before and after 2015?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84020/35864. The setup there is slightly more complex, because it also deals with `origdate`, but you should be able to adapt it to your situation by dropping that bit of the logic.

Comment: Also relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346270/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444095/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426247/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of the answer linked in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibcheck{recent}{
\iffieldint{year}
  {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2000}
     {\skipentry}
     {}}
  {\skipentry}}
 \defbibcheck{older}{
\iffieldint{year}
  {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{2000}
     {\skipentry}
     {}}
  {\skipentry}}
\begin{document}
\textcite{cms,coleridge,companion,cotton,ctan,doody,gaonkar,gaonkar:in,geer,gerhardt,gillies}
\printbibliography[check=recent,title=Recent]
\printbibliography[check=older,title=Older]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]